# Why are my links created in a subfolder url having only one single store in Magento

Tags: magento, url

I only have one `Website -> Store -> View`, and even so I get all my `URL's` linking to products, categories, pages, etc... as `http://www.website.com/default/category/product-1.html`

When it should be `http://www.website.com/category/product-1.html`. "`default/`" is always present.

I would like to remove the unnecessary `default/` subfolder in my URLs.

[image]
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `System -> Configuration -> General -> Web -> URI Options`

Here you can see the first option as `Add Store Code to Urls` select it to `NO` and save the config.
close the browser and look your store now.
It will work.

Comment: I didn't see that option. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot have multiple stores with the same store code.

Navigate to `System >Configuration > Web > Url options >  Add Store Code to Urls` and set it to `No`

**Note**: When using `Store Code in URLs`, in some cases system may not work properly if URLs without Store Codes are specified in the third party services (like paypal)